# Simplest complex curves with isomorphic Jacobian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Hi.

What are the simplest examples to have in mind of non-isomorphic smooth (complex) algebraic curves with isomorphic jacobian variety?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not easy to give equations of non-isomorphic Riemann surfaces whose Jacobians are isomorphic as (unpolarized) Abelian varieties.

Some explicit examples can be found in the paper by Everett W. Howe [*Infinite Families of Pairs of Curves Over $\mathbb{Q}$ with Isomorphic Jacobians*](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/72/2/327),  J. London Math. Soc. (2005) **72** (2), 327-350.

A preprint version of the paper is also available in the arXiv website, see http://arxiv.org/abs/math.AG/0304471. In Section 8 you can find the examples you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Francesco! 

But this does not exactly answers to the question: what are the SIMPLEST examples...

But one can also argue that the question is not rigourously stated, I agree.



Comment: You are welcome. Right, it is not clear what "simplest" should mean in this case. At any rate, in Howe's paper there are examples given by pairs of genus $2$ curves, which is of course the lowest possible genus. In this sense, such examples might be considered "simple".

Answer (score 3):

Slightly tangential -- the following paper of Bjorn Poonen offers some interesting computational perspectives on curves of genus at least $2$ which is as Francesco mentions, the lowest possible genus where such examples exist. This seems like it might be relevant.

http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/ants2.pdf

I think the following is an interesting question to ask over a fixed number field $K$: Can one make tables of genus $2$ curves over $K$ ordered in some lexicographic fashion by the invariants? Perhaps the curves would be modelled by singular plane curves $y^2 = f(x)$ where $f$ has degree $5$ or $6$. The first pair $(X,Y)$ with isomorphic Jacobian variety to occur in this table might satisfy the request that the pair $(X,Y)$ be the "simplest" such pair to be defined over $K$.

Poonen notes that not every not every hyperelliptic curve has a model of the form $y^2 = f(x)$ over
$k$ a field, because the quotient of the curve by its hyperelliptic involution might be a twist of $\mathbb{P}^1$ i.e. birational over $k$ to a conic in $\mathbb{P}^2$ without a $k$-rational point. However when $g$ is even, it seems to turn out (I'm not sure why) that the $k$-form of $\mathbb{P}^1$ has a $k$-point and the hyperelliptic curve has a model $y^2 = f(x)$, so for $g = 2$ we should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an abstract nonsense example with some lies I believe can be fixed.

We (lie) have a surjection $M_2 \to A_2$, where $M_2$ is the $6$ dimensional moduli space of genus $2$ curves and $A_2$ ppa surfaces. This is a lie but if we take $\bar{M_2}$ and smart compactify jacobians this is probably true.

Thus we need only find two abelian surfaces with two different polarization.

For an elliptic curve $E$, take $E \times E$ and now one polarization is a sum of fibers i.e $O(1,1)$, and the other is a diagonal plus a fiber i.e $O(\Delta + O(0,1)$. Both have $ch_2 =1$ and so give a principal polarization.