# Non-isomorphic curves with isomorphic Jacobians

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

There are many examples of pairs of non-isomorphic curves of genus 2 or 3 whose Jacobians are isomorphic as (unpolarized) Abelian varieties, see e.g. [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128593/simplest-complex-curves-with-isomorphic-jacobian) and its answers. This is relatively easy because almost all principally polarized Abelian varieties of dimension 2 and 3 are Jacobians.  Ciliberto and Van der Geer have constructed families of examples in genus 4 (in *Classication of Algebraic Varieties*, Contemp. Math. 162, AMS (1994)). Does anyone know examples in genus $\geq 5$?